# What's the book by Heinlein that contains all other books?

Tags: story-identification, books, robert-a-heinlein

I remember a thread here in the SciFi Stack Exchange about the longest sci-fi series. Someone mention a standalone Heinlein book that seemed to somehow include all other books ever written in its story. Does anybody know which book is that?

Comment: For reference, [here's](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/221/31394) the post you were thinking of.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Heinlein's [*Number of the Beast*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Number_of_the_Beast_%28novel%29) features a vehicle that can travel through space and time and to fictional worlds such as Oz and Barsoom.

Comment: "Gay Deceiver! Bounce, bounce, bounce!"

Comment: I tried to get someone to name a boat "Gay Deceiver" once ... they declined.

Comment: @joshbirk That's what our boat is called. We sort of had to when we got assigned 666 as registration number by the harbour-master. About once a year someone asks if it is after the book. Most of the time people think it is a homosexual thing. We get some really strange looks sometimes.

Comment: I'd also say The Number of the Beast is probably the book that includes all the other books. Characters from different stories appear in it: it has Lazarus Long from Time Enough for Love and Manuel Garcia O'Kelly-Davis from The Moon is a Harsh Mistress. He also introduces his World as Myth idea in this book,  I think, and there's a scene near the end where characters from many different fictional stories appear.

Comment: Don't forget the his and hers "facilities" from Oz.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on when in his career you're thinking of, and how complete an "all" you're insisting on, "[Time Enough For Love](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Enough_for_Love)" references many/most of his other books and embeds [at least two sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Enough_for_Love#Connections_to_other_books) that are novella-to-novel-length in their own right.

[image: Time Enough For Love]

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of completeness (although I think accepted answer *The Number of the Beast* is the most all-encompassing of Heinlein's "multiverse" novels), I'll throw in *The Cat Who Walks Through Walls*.

It weaves together characters and storylines from a variety of other Heinlein novels, most prominently *The Moon Is A Harsh Mistress* and *Time Enough For Love*.

In spirit and tone, though, it functions as a sort of sequel to *The Number of the Beast*. Not for reasons of any narrative continuity between the two, but because each is a freewheeling parodic adventure within the conventions of a particular genre. Where *Beast* was primarily a romp through the conventions of pulp sci-fi. *The Cat* is Heinlein at play with the tropes of hard-boiled detective fiction. Flawed tough-guy hero, mysterious femme fatale, inexplicable murder to open the action - it's all swiped from the noir playbook.

Finally, the spacetime-travelling fictional-world-visiting Gay Deceiver from *Beast* also makes a reappearance in *To Sail Beyond The Sunset*, but there it's more of a walk-on cameo at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure whether this is what you’re looking for, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Us,_The_Living:_A_Comedy_of_Customs#Connections_to_other_Heinlein_works) says,

> ***For Us, the Living***  contains many foreshadowings of Heinlein's later writings. 
> The 2086 of the book has a significant resemblance to both [*Beyond This Horizon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_This_Horizon) and the Earth of [*Methuselah’s Children*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methuselah%27s_Children). 
> Other familiar elements include the "Covenant" from "[Coventry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coventry_(short_story))",
> a variation on [*Starship Troopers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troopers)’  suffrage only through federal service, rolling roads and a cat as a minor character.                … (and more)

… and there are similar remarks in the introduction to the book.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like they were talking about his collection [The Past Through Tomororow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Past_Through_Tomorrow). It's not all the books he's ever written, but it's a really good overview of his future history. The stories are presented in chronological order relative to one another.