# Space craft takes group of people to various planets which turn out to be from their imaginations or books they have read

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

A space craft takes the group to various planets. These turn out to be from their imaginations or books they have read, such as Alice in Wonderland. They are pursued by men in black (hats?).

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51772/whats-the-book-by-heinlein-that-contains-all-other-books

Answer (score 37):

There is a reasonable likelihood that this is Heinlein's [*The Number of the Beast*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1541064).

The "spacecraft" is a flying car named "Gay Deceiver", and the people comprise two couples.

They visit Earth on alternate timeline, Mars in the Burroughs timeline ([Barsoom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barsoom)), Oz and others. Heinlein's world-as-myth concept is first introduced in this book.

There is an extended subplot concerning who is to be the officer in charge with all four crew taking a turn at it before one of their number of selected by consensus.

Comment: That's a hell of a name.

Comment: Yes, this is likely it.  The bad guys are referred to as Black Hats as well. A good book to forget, IMHO.

Comment: @OrganicMarble All Heinlein books are good to forget.

Comment: Starship Troopers is still one of my favorites. I first read it when I was ten, with Chinook choppers flying over my house for rappelling practice (jump troops) at Camp Arthur Currie (since then renamed Currie Barracks, and later CFB Calgary)

Comment: I like most Heinlein up to and including The Moon Is A Harsh Mistress.  After that....OMG.

Answer (score 15):

This vague description sounds like you may be thinking of Robert A. Heinlein's *"The Number of the Beast--"* [(Wikipedia page)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Number_of_the_Beast_(novel)) [(ISFDB page)](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1451)

Comment: A day late and a dollar short :-)

Comment: Meh. I took the time to find the link in Wikipedia as well - dmckee posted his _while_ I was typing mine.

Comment: The problem with not being the [fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) is that you.get.shot.

Comment: Given his 666 rep, he may be the best person around to post this answer

Comment: :) It wasn't 666 at the time I posted it...

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Mark of a true visionary to know that in advance ;)

Comment: Jeff, if you want to game the system on fastest gun in the west questions (and one with a Heinlein story as the answer is certainly that) you can enter a short, simple answer, and then progressively improve it—I did a little of that with mine here. Bear in mind that some people don't like to see a really extreme version of that strategy, preferring to see a few substantial edits to many very small ones. And you can go much father than I did here (I was away from the house, and ran out of time to continue). And of course, you win some and lose some.

Comment: @dmckee - I'm not really into trying to 'game the system'; I'm here more-or-less simply because it's interesting, sometimes I can help, and sometimes I can pick the brain of the collective (in no particular order). That's what the site is for, after all; it's not (supposed to be) a "rep contest".

Comment: I understand, and I generally only spend the effort on questions that involve stories that are somewhat obscure and which I feel are good enough that they should get more attention. [scifi.se] is a *very* fickle mistress when it comes to awarding rep. Sometimes a question  gets many votes while an earlier one on the same story drew few for no obvious reason. I've been on both sides of that as well as on both side of fastest-gun-in-the-west. I write comment like the above because I never know if someone on the short end is able to shrug it off or is feeling really burned. Cheers.