# Story identification: incomplete science fiction series by a now dead author

Tags: story-identification, books

Looking for a record length, multiple volume science fiction series about space exploration/space faring activity/space based warfare. This series was featured in a Wikipedia article regarding record length fiction or science fiction. (possibly word count)

The original author died, and a team of authors have attempted (and so far failed) to finish his work.

The series is not Dune. Not Wheel of Time. Not Riftwar Saga or Terry Pratchett.

Comment: Related: [What is the longest science fiction saga in books?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/200/31394) Your answer may well be in there somewhere.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to see what other details may be helpful in identifying this work. As it stands, your question is too broad.

Comment: Can you say anything else?  When did the original author die?

Comment: You might also look here: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AuthorExistenceFailure

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean *Perry Rhodan*?  It has been published weekly (in German) since 1961, now amounting to hundreds of thousands of pages.  Both of the original creators are deceased.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I checked that one out too, but what I'm looking for is a series where new authors have attempted to finish/continue with a large manuscript but have not been successful. I feel like that is they key to figuring this out.

Answer (score 3):

It could be the *Foundation/Empire/Robot* series by Isaac Asimov.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundation_series):

> The series is set in the same universe as Asimov's first published novel, *Pebble in the Sky*, although *Foundation* takes place about 10,000 years later. *Pebble in the Sky* became the basis for the Empire series. Then, at some unknown date (prior to writing *Foundation's Edge*) Asimov decided to merge the Foundation/Empire series with his Robot series. Thus, all three series are set in the same universe, giving them a combined length of 15 novels, and a total of about 1,500,000 words (see the List of books below). The merge also created a time-span of the series of around 20,000 years.

- **multiple volume science fiction series about space exploration/space faring activity/space based warfare.**

  More about space faring activity and space based warfare.
- **The original author died, and a team of authors have attempted (and so far failed) to finish his work.**

  This is a partial fit. There was a collection of short stories by other authors and, after Asimov's death, a new trilogy by Gregory Benford, Greg Bear and David Brin.

Comment: I wouldn't call this 'record length'. As near as I can tell, the contenders for that title would have to be Frank Herbert's _Dune_, Robert Jordan's _Wheel of Time_, or L. Ron Hubbard's _Mission Earth_. Since the querent has explicitly ruled out _Dune_ and _Wheel of Time_, I'd lean toward _Mission Earth_, but I've never read any of Elron's tripe.